# Possible to create a map with route planning via multiple preset locations depending on distance?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

So, Imagine I have a car planning to travel some distance.
Is it possible to create a map on my web page, putting planned route (from location to location), my consumption of my car and it would tell me where I could fill it up again. But only via my preset location.
Could I use some of the API in google maps to create this?

Something similar to this would be Tesla route planner: https://www.tesla.com/en_CA/trips?redirect=no

Answer (score 0):

You can start off with Maps JavaScript API's [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) which calculates directions between locations that also contains the distance and duration for the route.

Also check out the example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

Hope this helps!